# Removal of rows in table not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to remove the rows of data that are inside of my table when a button is clicked.  My current code removes the row content after 1-3 presses, but I was hoping it would clear the content and then add the new content all in one press.

Here is the code I'm using...

```
private void newTasksActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int sizeOfLL = taskLL.size();
    DefaultTableModel textArea = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

    int r = textArea.getRowCount();

    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        textArea.removeRow(i);   
    }

    for (int i =0; i < sizeOfLL; i++) {
        textArea.addRow(new Object[]{taskLL.get(i).index, taskLL.get(i).taskName, taskLL.get(i).taskDes, taskLL.get(i).taskStatus});
    }       
}
```

5 rows of data is shown in the jTable.  After pressing the button again, two rows of data are deleted.  If I press the button and 2nd time 1 row of data is left.  Pressing the button a third time all rows of are removed and the next button press inserts 5 rows of data.  Ideally I would want this button to always clear the row field and then add the data being inserted.  Making every button press show fresh data as I have three buttons that have the exact same code but enter different data into the jTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try counting backwards from r-1 to 0. The problem is that the first row is removed, shifting the second row to that index. When you increment i, you are indexing past that row.

```
...
for (int i = r-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
...
```